# Select top ten data from database and write into string array

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I would like to get top 10 data(by frequency) from database table word and pass the words to string array.
Table Name: word
colums: word, frequency

Here is my code but i dont know what kind of loop should i write into if statement;

```
 string[] kyt = new string[10];
            SqlCommand com;
            string cmr;
            con3.Open();
            cmr = "SELECT TOP (10) frequency FROM word GROUP BY frequency ORDER BY frequency DESC";
            com = new SqlCommand (cmr, con3);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read()) { 



            }
```

Comment: `SELECT frequency FROM word GROUP BY frequency ORDER BY count(*) DESC limit 10`

Comment: and how can i pass these 10 values in to string array?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT frequency 
FROM word 
GROUP BY frequency 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC 
limit 10
```

and then

```
List<string> frequencies = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read()) { 
    string frequency = reader["frequency"].ToString();
    frequencies.Add(frequency);
}
```